# Is there a more intuitive way to write updateforms?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am currently working on a webapp for timemanagement and shiftplaning.
First things first, I'm pretty new at webops and Django.

With my new knowledge I was digging through different blogs ( for example [Django Girls](https://djangogirls.org/)  - which is almost pretty good!) and through stackoverflow.

But there is one question which bothers me. Is there any different way to update saved form data without using

`class Foo(generic.UpdateView):`

for example by using a `ModelForm` which allready displays the value that we want to change?

I am a little bit confused at the moment, and like the thing that I can insert HTML-code to the `ModelForm`-forms. If you can give me any hints, tips or clues to insert HTML-code to my `UpdateView`  I'd appreciate that.

Thank you.

**EDIT**
I am using Django 1.8 and `django-crispy-forms`

That's my current `UpdateView`

```
class ShiftUpdate(generic.UpdateView):
   model = Shift
   fields = [ 'start','ending','break',]
   template_name = "shifts/shift_edit_form.html"

   def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
      obj = super(ShiftUpdate, self).get_object(*args, **kwargs)
      if obj.user.email == self.request.user.email or self.request.user.is_admin == True or self.request.user.is_manager == True:
        return obj
      raise PermissionDenied()
```

In `ModelForm` you can use a `FormHelper` from `django-crispy-forms` which gives you a `form.helper.layout` where you can insert HTML code intuitively.

Comment: Your question might be clearer if you explain what you mean by 'insert HTML code' and 'update saved form data'. Show your update view, and explain what you don't like about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to edit those forms while reading that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502106/crspy-forms-layout-not-work-for-django-inline-formset).
So it's possible to write a `UpdateView` while using the `django-crispy-forms`'s `FormHelper` (you can find the docu [here](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/form_helper.html)).